# copy delivery address fields to billing address fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing web form. I just want to as button (called same as delivery address)
So if user fills only delivery address and click on this button.
then it copy all values and fill to billing address fields.

thnk u in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<input id="copyFrom"/>
<input id="pasteTo"/>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
var valueToCopy = $("#copyFrom").val();
$("#pasteTo").val(valueToCopy);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/htt9fLzd/

You can add as many inputs as you want. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the values over on the button click.

```
 $('#button').click(function () {
    $('#billing_address').val($('#delivery_address').val());
    $('#billing_city').val($('#delivery_city').val());
    $('#billing_state').val($('#delivery_state').val());
    $('#billing_zip').val($('#delivery_zip').val());
 });
```